# Expected number of different object

Tags: probability

> Let us assume that there are $n$ different types of objects, and I have $m$ objects in total. What is the expected number of different objects that I have?

Let us number the distinct object types $1,2, \cdots, n$. I thought about letting $X$ be the number of different objects I have, then $$X = \sum_{i=1}^n I_i, $$ where $I_i$ denotes whether or not I have the object type $i$, for each $i \in \{1,2, \cdots, n \}$. Then $$E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^n E[I_i], $$ but I don't know how to compute the expectation of $I_i$.

Comment: should we assume that each object is drawn uniformly from the $n$ possibilities independently?  Assuming that, Hint:  the probability that you get object $i$ plus the probability that you don't get it is $1$.

Comment: probabilistic pigeonhole principle ?

Comment: @lulu Yes, we can assume independent and uniform distribution of the object types. However, I don't see how to use what you mentioned. Do you mean to say that I should condition on whether I have the object type or not?

Comment: For a particular object, the probability that you do not have it is $\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^m$. So, the probability that you do have it is: $P[I_i] = 1-\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^m$. And then by linearity of expectation, $E[X] = nE[I_i]$ I think.

Comment: No.  I mean to call attention to the fact that it is easier to compute the probability that you don't see object $i$.

Comment: I see now what you meant, thank you!